# Проблема при запуске файлов

Tags: python, консоль

Я написал программу которая должна запустить 2 exe-файла в одном окне консоли, при том что она сама работает в режиме без консоли `pyw`.

```
os.system('hello.exe\ngetchar_pro.exe')
```

**Она запускает первую программу, а вторая не запускается.**

`getchar_pro.exe` - заглушка на C++ принимающая на ввод строку (чтобы не закрывалось окошко)

getchar_pro по отдельности запускается, а когда ставишь второй строкой просто игнорируется. Ошибок не выскакивает. Как это исправить

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`os.system("hello.exe && getchar_pro.exe")` должно работать